# hdfs + namenode + edit files increasing with huge size and how to limit the size of edit files

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, ambari, hdp, namenode

we have HDP cluster with 7 datanodes machines

under `/hadoop/hdfs/namenode/current/`

we can see more then `1500` edit files
each file is around `7M` to `20M` as the following

```
7.8M    /hadoop/hdfs/namenode/current/edits_0000000002331008695-0000000002331071883
7.0M    /hadoop/hdfs/namenode/current/edits_0000000002331071884-0000000002331128452
7.8M    /hadoop/hdfs/namenode/current/edits_0000000002331128453-0000000002331189702
7.1M    /hadoop/hdfs/namenode/current/edits_0000000002331189703-0000000002331246584
11M     /hadoop/hdfs/namenode/current/edits_0000000002331246585-0000000002331323246
8.0M    /hadoop/hdfs/namenode/current/edits_0000000002331323247-0000000002331385595
7.7M    /hadoop/hdfs/namenode/current/edits_0000000002331385596-0000000002331445237
7.9M    /hadoop/hdfs/namenode/current/edits_0000000002331445238-0000000002331506718
9.1M    /hadoop/hdfs/namenode/current/edits_0000000002331506719-0000000002331573154
9.0M    /hadoop/hdfs/namenode/current/edits_0000000002331573155-0000000002331638086
7.8M    /hadoop/hdfs/namenode/current/edits_0000000002331638087-0000000002331697435
7.8M    /hadoop/hdfs/namenode/current/edits_0000000002331697436-0000000002331755881
8.0M    /hadoop/hdfs/namenode/current/edits_0000000002331755882-0000000002331814933
9.8M    /hadoop/hdfs/namenode/current/edits_0000000002331814934-0000000002331884369
11M     /hadoop/hdfs/namenode/current/edits_0000000002331884370-0000000002331955341
8.7M    /hadoop/hdfs/namenode/current/edits_0000000002331955342-0000000002332019335
7.8M    /hadoop/hdfs/namenode/current/edits_0000000002332019336-0000000002332074498
```

is it possible to minimize file size by some `HDFS` configuration? ( or minimize edit files numbers )
since we have small disks and the disk is now `100%`

```
/dev/sdb                   100G   100G     0 100% /hadoop/hdfs
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure the `dfs.namenode.num.checkpoints.retained` and
`dfs.namenode.num.extra.edits.retained` properties to control the size
of the directory that holds the NameNode edits directory.

> - `dfs.namenode.num.checkpoints.retained`: The number of image checkpoint
>   files that are retained in storage directories. All edit logs
>   necessary to recover an up-to-date namespace from the oldest retained
>   checkpoint are also retained.
> - `dfs.namenode.num.extra.edits.retained`: The number of extra transactions that should be retained beyond what is minimally
>   necessary for a NameNode restart. This can be useful for audit
>   purposes, or for an HA setup where a remote Standby Node may have been
>   offline for some time and require a longer backlog of retained edits
>   in order to start again.

Resource: https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.1.5/data-storage/content/properties_to_set_the_size_of_the_namenode_edits_directory.html

Comment: what are the minimal values?

Comment: Actually I dont know but try to set it for example, 50GB. It may help you